# How to add custom options for cart items

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, cart-items

I have created a virtual product, and programmatically wants to add custom options in cart item without adding option in product custom option tab becasue it will be different in different cases.

For this I have used below code :

```
    ...
    $additionalOptions = array(
                         array(
                             'code' => 'title',
                             'label' => 'Title',
                             'value' => $title,
                             'print_value' => $title,
                         ),
                         array(
                             'code' => 'group',
                             'label' => 'Group',
                             'value' => $Value,
                             'print_value' => $Value, 

                        )
                    );

    $item->addOption(array(
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => serialize($additionalOptions),
                    ));
    $item->save();
    ...
```

But it is not working.

How to add custom options for cart items not for product?